# SQL Error: 1364 - Field 'buys' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, sql, mybb

I am getting this error in mybb SQL table:

SQL Error: 1364 - Field 'buys' doesn't have a default value 
Query: INSERT INTO mybb_bank_post ('pid','cost') VALUES ('1680','10000')

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You need to specify a value for the buys column too.

Comment: With questions like this it's useful to publish the table definition.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests that `buys` is declared `NOT NULL`.  So, you need to assign it a value when you insert into the table:

```
INSERT INTO mybb_bank_post (pid, cost, buys)
    VALUES (1680, 10000, 0);
```

Or, declare the table so `buys` is not `NOT NULL` -- that is `NULL` values are allowed.  Or, provide a default value in the table definition.

Note:  Do not use single quotes for column names or for numeric constants.  Only use single quotes for strings and date constants.